# One to Many relationship in entity framework without Code First

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I need to configure a one to many relationship without using code first design in entity framework. I know that's a silly constraint but it is what was asked for an assignment.  I've created my database with these tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MissionQuestions] (
[MissionQuestionId] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[missionID]         INT           NOT NULL ,
[userID]            INT           NOT NULL,
[missQuestion]      VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[missAnswer]        VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MissionQuestionId] ASC), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_MissionQuestions_Missions] FOREIGN KEY ([missionID])     REFERENCES [Missions]([missionID]), 
CONSTRAINT [FK_MissionQuestions_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([userID]) REFERENCES [Users]([userID]) 
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Missions] (
[missionID]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[missionName]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[missionPresName] VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[missionLanguage] VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[missionClimate]  VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[missionReligion] VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[missionImg]      VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([missionID] ASC)
);
```

I have a Users table too but I don't think it's relavent in this issue
and here are my model classes

```
[Table("Missions")]
public class Missions
 {

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int missionID { get; set; }
    public String missionName { get; set; }
    public String missionPresName { get; set; }
    public String missionLanguage { get; set; }
    public String missionClimate { get; set; }
    public String missionReligion { get; set; }
    public String missionImg { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MissionQuestions> MisisonQuestions { get; set; }

}

[Table("MissionQuestions")]
public class MissionQuestions
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int missionQuestionID { get; set; }
    public String missQuestion { get; set; }
    public String missAnswer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Missions")]
    public virtual int missionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Missions Missions { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public virtual int userID { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

To describe these tables briefly, thhere should be a selection of "Missions" where people can ask and answer questions about each mission. Thus each mission has 0 - * "missionQuestions" 
I thought I had everything set up properly but I got this error

> MissionQuestions_Missions_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role >'MissionQuestions_Missions_Source' in relationship 'MissionQuestions_Missions'. >Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper >bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

I'm guessing that the error is in the way the database is set up, and that could probably be fixed using code first to design the database but I'm working on an assignment where I was told not to use code first. Any ideas how to specify the multiplicity to match?

Comment: Can you show us the Diagram of these two tables captured in SSMS?

Comment: Can you show your DbContext code and at what point you get error